# Changing subscription price on Google Play store in-app

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

For testing a subscription I added the price as $1. But now I need to change the price. I know we cannot change a subscription price but is there any way we can contact Google?

Comment: are u able to create another subscription plan with a different price?

Comment: yes but I do not want to create another. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if contacting them would get your price changed, but you can give it a try. They will probably redirect you to their In-Billing Subscription [page](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html):

> To change the price of a subscription, you can publish a new subscription product ID at a new price, then offer it in your app instead of the original product. Users who have already purchased will continue to be charged at the original price, but new users will be charged at the new price.

Here's their developer [support](https://developer.android.com/support.html) page, just navigate to Billing and Reporting.